# PHPMailer destroys the While loop

Tags: php, while-loop, phpmailer

I want to send e-mails to multiple persons in a while loop using PHPmailer. But as soon as the loop gets to the row `include '../email/PHPMailerAutoload.php';` it stops inside the while loop. The full code looks like this

```
<?php
    $result = $con->prepare('SELECT * from table WHERE Date = ?');
    $result->execute([$Date]);
    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){
        $Email=$row['Email'];   
        include '../email/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
        email_function($Email);
    }
?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Move the `include` to occur before the loop. Always when developing and testing PHP code, enable error display. At the top of your script, `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`  Most likely you will find PHP complaining that you are attempting to redeclare a class or similar.  It is almost never necessary or advisable to `include/require` a file inside a loop.

Comment: You are including the autoload EVERT TIME ROUND THE LOOP Title should be _"How have I destroyed this while loop"_

Comment: Thank you all, especially to Michael Berkowski :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PHPMailerAutoload.php` must be included/called once! Please try this:

```
include '../email/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$result = $con->prepare('SELECT * from table WHERE Date = ?');
$result->execute([$Date]);
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){
    $Email=$row['Email'];   
    email_function($Email);
}
```